# Prediction of flight delay. What kind of information is available to a company at the moment of scheduled departure of a flight?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport-operations

I am working on a data science task of trying to predict the departure delay of flights, but I don't have much knowledge of aviation itself. I have a dataset that contains some information of the flights as origin and destination airports, airline, scheduled time of departure, etc. But unfortunatelly they seem to have very few predictive power on delays.

I have also a set of five variables that do predict somewhat the delays. They are 'Carrier Delay', 'Weather Delay', 'NAS Delay', 'Security Delay', 'Late Aircraft Delay'. But I don't have additional information on what they represent. I found this link  https://aspm.faa.gov/aspmhelp/index/Types_of_Delay.html that explains somewhat. However It is not clear for me which one, if any, of these variables I can use, since I dont' know if I would have any of these informations at the moment of scheduled departure. Therefore, using them would be cheating somehow. What do you think?

Sorry If this question doesnt belong here. I just thought that maybe someone here would know something about this kind of information.

EDIT: In this case, 'I' would be the airline itself. The exercise is to make a model that would use all the data that a company has available till the moment of scheduled departure to predict the delay.

On my dataset I have different information, as the actual arrival delay, which naturally is very correlated with the departure delay. But I cannot use it naturally, as I don't know the arrival delay at the moment of scheduled departure. Doing so would be cheating. My question is whether using these 5 variables above would be also cheating.

Comment: Are “you” the general flying public? The pilot/company? Some other entity?  Obviously, “insiders” would have different access to different variables compared to the general public

Comment: You have some data, then 5 data points that you don't have for future flights -- it's not clear, at least to me, what the question is. As Jimmy notes, airlines have a trove of their own data that they use. If you're asking for data, it's off-topic here. If you're asking how to predict the delay, then obviously have lots of insider data (I assure you I'm **not** being insincere). And finally, if the question is how to use the FAA data to make a statistical model for future predictions, then Cross Validated Stack Exchange *may* be a much better site (check their help page for what's on-topic).

Comment: "I" would be an insider, specifically the airline.

Comment: @ymb1 I added some information

Comment: @Manveru: Based on your edit, you want to predict the arrival delay that isn't due to a departure delay, is that correct? If yes, wouldn't the scheduled flight time vs actual flight time help find a pattern, say in winter months? Also please try to make the title clearer, grammatically it's not clear at all. I'm happy to help, but first I need to understand what the actual question is.

Comment: @ymb1 not exactly. I want to predict departure delay of future flights. In my dataset I have information of departure and arrival delays of past flights, among other info. What I say that I assume I cannot use information of arrival delay to model departure delay since it happens later.

Comment: @Manveru: But, it *is* indicative of a departure delay, so why is it "cheating"? Are you asking "Can I use it?" Or are you asking "Am I right not to use it?" Or something else?

Comment: @ymb1, yes it is indicative. But if I want to use my model in real life, I can not predict the departure delay by using information that I ll only have in the future, which is the case of arrival delay of the same flight. I need to use only information that I have prior the prediction moment

Comment: @Manveru: I think I understand now. Correct me if I'm wrong. You want to predict delays, before delays start happening to other airlines (the FAA data), is that correct?

Comment: You’ll have EDCT and GDP info at departure time, plus your own delays due to the inbound flight arriving late, missing/timed-out crews or maintenance. You’ll also know the ETE for the route you’ve chosen (usually to avoid weather), though ATC may change it.

Comment: You may want to clarify how far ahead you are attempting to predict. “At the moment of scheduled departure” is too late; if you are NOT leaving at that very moment you will know exactly why because all the information will be available to you right then, and no amount of prediction will prevent it. Also, different factors are known at different times. For example, if the airplane you are using hasn’t departed on the prior leg you will know hours prior. But an unruly passenger at door closing, last second security delay...

Comment: Are you trying to predict based on known current conditions: weather, airport conditions etc  or are you trying to use statistical analysis of past flight data to make the prediction? Or a combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airlines track delay rates (leaving the gate more than 15 minutes after the departure time) as "chargeable" and "non-chargeable" (chargeable, as in "blame-able" you might say, to the OEM), to separate causes that are the airplane's fault and causes that are the airline's fault or due to other external factors.

Chargeable delays are due to mechanical issues that a related to the airplanes own reliability.  These delays are considered the responsibility of the Manufacturer to address with design changes or maintenance guidance.  The industry standard for Chargeable delays (because something on the airplane broke) is not more than 1% of departures, generally expressed as Dispatch Reliability of 99% or better.  A lot of airplanes are less than that, but under about 97 or 98 % is starting to look pretty bad and a mature design that is well executed should have no problem maintaining 99% or very close to it.

Whatever the number is, at a mature airline flying a mature design, the number will be fairly consistent over time and you can make assumptions about future delay rates based on current delay rates or their trends.

Non-chargeable delays are those that are the airline's fault (airline-induced maintenance, delays leaving overnight maintenance, weather delays, ATC-related delays that show up in the overall dispatch reliability or schedule completion data but are not the fault of the airplane itself).  These delays are also carefully tracked and at a mature operator the numbers should be fairly consistent, notwithstanding crises that arise out of nowhere and skew the numbers from time to time.

So all those delay categories mentioned in your post would be tracked by the airline and maintained in an internal database and used to forecast various things, like the need to keep spare aircraft that sit on standby to fill in for cancellations, that sort of thing.

So to answer the specific question, the airline will maintain a detailed database of departure delays for all causes, in order to be aware of and act on, to the extent it can, the source of the delays, to keep its fleet wide departure delay and cancellation rate, and schedule completion rate, within a specification.

Schedule completion rate is the key number at the end of it all, a measure of the success in getting passenger X from point A to point B, eventually.  Spare aircraft kept on hand to fill in when flights are cancelled won't help with technical delay rates, but will greatly improve the Schedule Completion Rate.

There will be an internal reliability engineering organization at the airline responsible for tracking and acting on the information, and making forecasts for future requirements to head off problems before they come up.